# debounceTime to a service call

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to send this request using debounceTime method, to not send multiple times to server. but is not working. This service is being called instantly.

On drag'n'drop drop event I want to save positions with `saveWidgetsPosition` func.

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer !== event.container) {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data, event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }

    this.saveWidgetsPosition(this.columns);
  }
```

Function to save positions

```
saveWidgetsPosition(columns: any[]) {
    const columnsLabels = columns.map(x => x.map(y => y.label));

    this.userService.saveWidgetsPosition({ user: this.user, columns: columnsLabels})
        .pipe(debounceTime(5000))
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}
```

Comment: Code added on question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching this from the wrong direction. You need to debounce the execution of `this.userService.saveWidgetsPosition()`. Instead of debouncing processing the results of it.

You could do something like:

```
widgetPositions = new Subject<any>();
widgetPositions.pipe(
    debounceTime(5000),
    exhaustMap((data) => this.userService.saveWidgetPositions(data))
).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
});

saveWidgetsPosition(columns: any[]) {
    const columnsLabels = columns.map(x => x.map(y => y.label));

    widgetPositions.next({ user: this.user, columns: columnsLabels });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`debounceTime` isn't supposed to do that. Use `delay` instead.

> debounceTime: Discard emitted values that take less than the specified
>   time between output

You are looking for `delay`.
Your code should be:

```
this.userService.saveWidgetsPosition({ user: this.user, columns: columnsLabels})
      .pipe(delay(5000))
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: The delay does not happen, the request is sent at the same time independent of the milliseconds in delay()

Comment: try throttleTime()

Comment: Keeps logging console Instantly 